Is there a tool tracks which if else statement is used in a function?
Is there a tool tracks which if else statement is used in a function?
I dont have an error but I m sending a function and when it comes to a certain situation it does call another function and second function queries which situation occured. How to track which if else statement is used?

If you're debugging locally, you can add something like console logging (depending on your used tooling) to the contracts. Otherwise you can add events.

Not exactly what you are asking, but I had use solidity coverage to check lines of code being tested https://github.com/sc-forks/solidity-coverage.

Figured out the problem thx anyway.
